# Steam won't launch in Ubuntu 15.04 x64

Tags: steam, 15.04

After installing Steam in Ubuntu 15.04 x64 it won't start.

After trying this command in terminal `steam` I get this output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

And also `steam --reset` command gave this output:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/[USER]/.steam/registry.vdf’: No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/[USER]/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
```

I tried this and nothing else. I have AMD graphic card with Xorg drivers.

Answer (score 3):

check the [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/614458#614458) post.

This problem don't seem to affect the closed source drivers, only the open ones.

Answer (score 2):

After reinstalling Steam and then switching to proprietary drivers for my AMD graphic card it's finally working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me under Ubuntu 15.04 64bits with proprietary driver NVIDIA version 346 and the latest steam client:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib32/nvidia-346/:/usr/lib/nvidia-346/" steam
```