# Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+

Tags: software-installation, steam

Actually I have installed the new Ubuntu 15.04 64bit, and when I'm trying to install Steam on it, there is a problem.
In fact I have downloaded the deb package from steam website, installed it and when I start it nothing happens.
I tried to start it from terminal and what I've got

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: Are you by chance using a amd architecture?

Comment: I have this error on an AMD system with radeon GPU but I'm still on 14.10 - I did update the kernel in aptitude though so I presume the error stems from there. From my update log I've got `linux-image-3.16.0-41-generic:amd64 (3.16.0-41.57, automatic)` whilst previously I was using `Linux 3.16.0-37-generic`.

Comment: Fix of moving libstdc++.so.6 appears to work.

Comment: You can also try solution as posted in https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/648953#648953 that I think is more elegant.

Answer (score 115):

This was originally a problem with Steam on Ubuntu 15.04/15.10.  Steam bundles old libs and are colliding with mesa drivers, that is also why closed drivers aren't seeing this problem. Update: It might also be that you are missing some things. See other mchid's answer.

There is an [open bug in Steam's github](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4768).

The current workaround is to remove the old lib version, at least until valve fixes the issue in their startup script or something like that.

So enter these folders and do this (ignore the `x86_64` if you only have a 32bit system):

```
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

If you have problem with the directory above then you should try this:

Some people have the `.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32`, others have only `.steam/ubuntu12_32`. If you don't have these folders, find the correct location by checking where your steam is looking for the user profile:

```
$ fgrep config=  /usr/games/steam
config=$HOME/.steam
```

Use that to find your lib location:

```
[config value] + /ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
   |
   \-> $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

It worked for me... but please note that if some game required that old lib from the steam runtime, it may crash (that is why valve should fix this)

**Edit 2015-08-22:**

As Steam now has a link in the `$HOME/.steam/root` that always points to the correct Steam install directory, this command should work for everybody and it simpler for a fast fix:

```
find $HOME/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/*/usr/lib/ -name "libstdc++.so.6" -exec mv "{}" "{}.bak" \; -print
```

Also, please remember that on each steam runtime update, you will probably need to run this.

**Edit 2016-02-16:**

Also see the **mchid** reply below, simply doing:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

might be enough to fix this.

**Edit 2016-10-23:**

For **ubuntu 16.10** the command was updated to remove more files that are breaking mesa drivers, so this new command should work:

```
find $HOME/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/*/usr/lib/ \( -name "libstdc++.so.6" -o -name "libgpg-error.so.0"  -o -name "libxcb.so.1" -o -name "libgcc_s.so.1" \) -exec mv "{}" "{}.bak" \; -print
```

For **NVIDIA closed source drivers**, see Vincent's reply below.

**Edit 2017-01-08:**

Probably final edit, the latest steam linux update should fix most, if not all problems! finally! :D

**Edit 2017-08-03:**

Sadly, returning from vacation found that some recent update again broke steam.
So if you get this when starting, just after update download:

```
process 23148: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file dbus-connection.c line 2688.
```

and then steam crash, then you are hitting [this](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5099) [bug](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5101), reported as non-fatal, but it do crash steam on same distros. workaround is this:

```
ln -s ${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 ${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/pinned_libs_32/libdbus-1.so.3
```

good luck

Comment: Hi, Not sure whether I'm a lone case, but I just installed the .deb package on my fresh 15.04 install and it works fine. A pity I can't play half the games though... on a count of being Unix.

Comment: @thenaglecode but you can still play many of the best ones (DOTA2, infinifactory, and kerbal space program are all there) and there are more all the time.

Comment: This is still broken in December? Wow. VALVE SUCKS.

Comment: @WarrenP because it's not broken, people are just merging bugs with different errors. This answer has nothing to do with the errors posted by the OP. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the renaming/removing of "libstdc++.so.6" helps!

Comment: It is quite difficult. I give up playing game on Linux. =[

Comment: @CasperLI running ``` find $HOME/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/*/usr/lib/ -name "libstdc++.so.6" -exec mv "{}" "{}.bak" \; -print ``` is "quite dificult"?! then switch to steamos or a supported ubuntu release. Problem solved. Either you want to play in linux or not, this one is not the excuse for stop doing it

Comment: All this tricks doesn't work in 16.10

Comment: @QkiZ: check the updated command above, it should work now also in 16.10

Comment: I uninstalled version from Steam and installed version from Ubuntu repo and now works.

Comment: Just a note, on 16.10 your command did not do the trick for me, however, the one found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/775667 did work.

Comment: I definitely appreciate your effort to keep this updated, by the way. I really wish Valve would get on this.

Comment: rjp's link did do the trick for steam on 16.10 for me. thanks

Answer (score 20):

Fastfix (tested on Ubuntu 15.04)

```
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1{,.disable}
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6{,.disable}
```

Comment: Hmm this looked like it was going to work - it certainly squashed one error message, but it's still saying it can't load swrast - -

Comment: You have to apply this again after each steam update.

Comment: again, this doesn't fix the OP error message

Comment: I was having the same problem as OP on Xenial 16.04 with the same error message, and this worked for me. I needed to run these commands once before launching Steam for the first time, then a second time after Steam's initial update.

Answer (score 18):

The following is from [Error in installing Steam on ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/648953#648953) and is by far the easiest answer to this question (as noted above by [tahtisilma](https://askubuntu.com/users/430110/tahtisilma)).  I would add that if you want to avoid the pain of having to use the command terminal each time, then  you can edit the desktop file either on your desktop, by right clicking and selecting properties and then replacing the commmand in the desktop file with the following:

```
sh -c "LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam"
```

### Short version:

Start steam in the terminal using:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

instead of just steam

### Long version:

Steam can’t open nouveau_dri.so, the shared library responsible for communicating with the graphics driver. To check if the driver is OpenGL enabled run:

```
DISPLAY=:0 glxinfo | grep -i direct
```

The output should be:

direct rendering: Yes
Running steam in debug mode:

```
DISPLAY=:0 LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose steam
```

Gives us the output where the following lines gives us hint:

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed     (/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-   runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `    GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-  gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so))
```

It seems that steam uses different version of libstdc++.so.6. Lets check which version steam uses:

```
ls -l ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6  

 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 19 Jul 18  2014  /home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386- linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.18
```

So Steam loaded LibC6 with ABI version 18 where driver expects version 20.The solution is to tell OS to preload the proper LibC6 version using  LD_PRELOAD variable:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

The somewhat non-intuitive $LIB parameter gets expanded in ld.so to the right path based on the platform of the process being started (man 8 ld.so for details).

You can create script with the following content to run it instead of steam:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Export so all child processes are affected as well
  export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6'
  export DISPLAY=:0
#export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose
steam
```

A better script could check if the global LibC6 version is newer than the one in STEAM_RUNTIME and only then LD_PRELOAD’s.

More details can be found on [here](https://wirejungle.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/how-to-fix-broken-steam-linux-client-with-radeon-graphics-driver-workaround/). Note that I tested it on Debian and now it has been tested on Ubuntu vivid 15.04 and works fine.

Comment: although the desktop file edit will work, I can not get the main menu (xubuntu) entry desktop file in .local/share/applications/steam.desktop to work unless I create the menu entry using alacarte, and then remove the desktop file steam.desktop in .local/share/applications/steam.desktop and then link to the desktop file from .local/share/applications like so:
    ln -s ~/Desktop/steam.desktop  ~/.local/share/applications/steam.desktop

Comment: I had initially moved the files, as some answers above suggested. But it was only with the exports you pointed that I've got steam working on my ubuntu 15.04. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Where is the heck `$LIB` variable is being set ?  A lot of people mention it, and it's nowhere  defined

Answer (score 8):

This works fine for me under Ubuntu 15.04 64bits with proprietary driver NVIDIA version 346 :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib32/nvidia-346/:/usr/lib/nvidia-346/" steam
```

Comment: Another fix had worked for me before but I had to re-install my Nvidia drivers after blacklisting my nouveau driver and then steam wouldn't launch so this fixed it this time, hopefully this problem gets fixed by the time Ubuntu 16.04 comes out

Comment: This should work on any nvidia version (credit : Alan Plum - https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3801#issuecomment-256324040 ): `NVIDIA_VERSION=$(nvidia-settings -q NvidiaDriverVersion | grep -oP "[0-9]{3}" | sed -n 1p); 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib32/nvidia-$NVIDIA_VERSION:/usr/lib/nvidia-$NVIDIA_VERSION" `

Answer (score 8):

This is a simple fix.

According to the error message, you are missing the following files:`r600_dri.so` and `swrast_dri.so`

Run the following commands to install these missing files:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

The problem should now be solved.

Please post any additional errors.

Comment: If any Valve staffers happen along, I have a question; Why doesn't the steam for ubuntu installer script probe the Mesa install and find missing parts and install them for me?

Comment: Not solved at all, the libs in question were already at their latest version.

Comment: This fixed it for me.  This should be the first thing you try.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines from [menasheh's comment on github issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3801#issuecomment-192819868) works with Ubuntu 15.10:

```
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6'
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Note that if Steam updates itself, you may need to enter these lines again.

Answer (score 1):

Fix for Ubuntu 16.04, Xenial Xerus, 64-bit

I've only had this problem with Steam since upgrading to 16.04, it worked fine on 14.04. I tried all the fixes above for older versions of Ubuntu.

The second part of [this solution](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus) worked for me.

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install wget gdebi libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386
$ wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
$ sudo gdebi steam.deb
```

Now I'm running L4D2 in Ubuntu again - excellent!

Comment: If you've already got dpkg, there's no need to install gdebi:
`sudo dpkg -i ./steam.deb`

Comment: gdebi will install dependencies, dpkg won't.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Turns out the Steam runtime version of `libgcc_s.so.1` was the culprit. Renaming the file fixed the issue for me:

```
$ cd ~/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
$ mv libgcc_s.so.1 libgcc_s.so.1.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

### 16.04 and later

<sub>[image: IMG:]</sub>  Steam can be install as a flatpak package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak # required in 16.04 only, not in later releases
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub com.valvesoftware.Steam
```

The first command to add ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak is not required in 18.04 and later because the flatpak package is in the default repositories.

Steam can be launched by clicking on its icon in the Dash or launched from the terminal with the following command:

```
flatpak run com.valvesoftware.Steam
```

Many games require an online purchase, but some popular games, such as Team Fortress 2, are free to play. When searching in the store, be sure to narrow results by the SteamOS/Linux operating system. Not all Linux games are compatible with your system, so make sure you check the requirements before purchasing games.