# Steam wont start up on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: steam

I get this error:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2015-11-23 19:36:32] Startup - updater built Nov  9 2015 18:23:22
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

When I try to run steam. What does this mean? (I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, so I don't have the hang of everything yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those viewing my question, another solution is to install the steam package from the website [here.](http://store.steampowered.com/about/)

Then if you get this error:

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Then simply type in

```
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

And hit ENTER.
Now, in your terminal, it should look like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkOXs.png)
If it does look something like that, then you did it correctly. DO NOT CLOSE THE TERMINAL, LEAVE IT OPEN JUST LIKE THAT! And now you will need to type in 'steam' and hit ENTER again. At this point it should be opening your steam. STILL, DO NOT CLOSE THE TERMINAL! THIS WILL CLOSE STEAM! Wait for steam to finish its updating, and soon steam should ACTUALLY open!

If steam actually works and opens for you, then you did this all correctly! If it doesn't work, then you made a mistake, or this just does not work for you. After doing this, you will never need to follow these instructions again. Steam should now always just open up when you click on the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in terminal :

```
mv $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.bak

mv $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

This solution may have solved steam errors like yours in other posts, e.g. this [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617358/problem-starting-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04-64-bit).
As it has not been marked as solved yet, please tell me if this works or not.

Comment: I actually already found a solution. I installed the newest steam packages from the website, and then i got another error. But in terminal i typed in:

cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak

                            then hit 'enter' then typed 'steam' and it worked

Comment: also, on another computer, it says "no such directory" when doing your thing.

Comment: @yeah_oh_yeah ones for 64bit and ones for 32bit run both.

Comment: @yeah_oh_yeah did this help if it did can you mark it as solved ?

Comment: When i did it on my friends Ubuntu computer, where he installed it with:
sudo apt-get install steam instead of installing the package from the website, it worked for him. So thanks! It fixed my friends issues, but i solved mine here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04