# Steam won't launch 16.04

Tags: 16.04, steam, 32-bit, mate

Every time I click on the steam application it will update but then the update box disappears and then nothing happens. How can I fix this? I'm using Ubuntu Mate and have a 32-bit system.

This is the output:

```
hershey@hershey-VGN-FZ180E:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-08-15 01:19:50] Startup - updater built Jul  8 2016 21:43:51
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Also there is nothing I could find to help me using 16.04

Comment: Run `steam` from terminal and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/812371/edit) your question with the output.

Comment: try launching it with `DISPLAY=:0 steam` do you get the same error?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm still learning the ins and outs of Ubuntu Mate. @Zanna

Comment: Nothing changed I got the same error.

Comment: OK, long shot, but try it with `DISPLAY=:0.0 steam` and check `echo $DISPLAY`... try matching the value so whatever you get from `echo $DISPLAY` use in `DISPLAY=.... steam`

Comment: It says that the value is 0 but when I do that it just gives me the error

Comment: Did you install steam using `sudo apt-get install steam` or did you download it from the site?

Comment: I used `sudo apt-get install steam`

Comment: @HersheyGamer Remove completely steam by executing `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge steam` and then delete the folders `~/.steam` and `~/.local/share/Steam`. Finally download and install the deb package from here: http://store.steampowered.com/about/ (it gives you a newer version of steam-launcher and it adds a ppa to your system for updates). See if that solves the problem.

Comment: @ThanosApostolou Nothing changed still have the same problem

Comment: @HersheyGamer add the output of `inxi -SMCGx` on your question so that I can see your system info.

Comment: Actually, try to delete the `libstdc++.so.6 file as shown here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts or here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/617358/problem-starting-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04-64-bit

Comment: @ThanosApostolou There was no output of `inxi -SMCGx` and deleting the file doesn't help anything

Comment: @HersheyGamer you need to install `inxi` first if it doesn't exist by `sudo apt install inxi`, sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this in terminal: `env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam`