# Ubuntu 16.04 will not resume from Suspend

Tags: 16.04, drivers, suspend, intel-graphics

I use to be able to suspend and resume just fine but recently I just get a blank screen whenever I suspend or close the laptop lid. The only system changes I can think of are some updates I recently installed. I also noticed that suspend works just fine when I have the Nvidia GPU selected in the Nvidia X Server Settings but not when I am using the Intel GPU. I need to use the Intel GPU for battery life and not being able to close the lid is quite frustrating.

I using a i7-6700HQ
and gtx 1060 notebook on 384.59 drivers

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggestion comes from an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/833258/682481) to another post on AskUbuntu. Credit to @ArnovanderWeijden:

---

Please keep in mind that rebooting requires you to hold the power button when it hangs. (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>prtscn/sysrq</kbd>+reisub doesn't work)

- step 1: reinstall you system without swap (if you encrypt your home
  directory that is)
- step 2: boot into your new installation but don't log in. go to tty1
  (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f1</kbd>)
- step 3: [upgrade your kernel to 4.7.6](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2016/10/update-to-linux-kernel-476-on-ubuntu.html)
- step 4: reboot (and hold the power button when it hangs to kill it)
  and log into tty1
- step 5: install the Nvidia drivers and prime

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

  `sudo apt update`

  `sudo apt install nvidia-367 nvidia-prime`

choose lightdm when prompted

- step 6: reboot and log into gnome.
- step 7: open a terminal and execute

  `sudo prime-select intel`

and reboot.

When grub shows up press 'e' and at the end of the line that starts with 'linux' add 'nomodeset'.

Press F10 to boot into your system

- step 8: log in (that's possible thanks to lightdm and nomodeset)

Download [this](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2016/10/update-to-linux-kernel-476-on-ubuntu.html) and install it. (your firefox will probably not work at this point. to get it to work execute `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache`)

```
sudo dpkg -i intel-grapics-update-tool_2.0.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
wget -q0 - https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-r | sudo apt-key add -
```

- step 9: run the program (its the only program that starts with
  'intel' in your dash. After it's finished execute a reboot (**this is
  the last reboot that requires you to kill your system**).
- step 10: (after entering nomodeset) boot the system and log in.
  Install all the updates and reboot.
- step 11: enter nomodeset and log in. install gksu (sudo apt install
  gksu) and run `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and add `nomodeset`
  after `quiet splash`. (you can run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` at
  this point to get the gdm3 login screen back)
- step 12: run 'gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom' and copy your
  ubuntu menuentry from /boot/grub/grub.cfg into it. remember to remove
  the nomodeset from 40_custom. name it 'ubuntu nvidia'
- step 13: create /usr/local/bin/intel (and nvidia) with the following
  code

  `#!/bin/bash`

  `prime-select intel`

  `grub-reboot 0`

and

```
#!/bin/bash

prime-select nvidia
grub-reboot 7
reboot
```

make them executable (and perhaps add them to visudo) and you are done!!
if steam doesn't work on intel see Edit ∞².

ooh and if `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` gives you errors you can find the missing firmware [here](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-graphics-update-tool/intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.2_amd64.deb). Read the readme file to find out how to install them (some need --install operator while others just work)

Comment: The links in this answer are dead. This is why you should include all crucial parts.