# I can't use Steam in general I dont know problem

Tags: steam

I think I downloaded Steam because I tried everything. I tried downloading it from the website. I tried downloading it from command. When I downloaded it from command it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
steam:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So I think its already downloaded but I cant find it. Please help, I'm an Ubuntu noob and I tried looking it up but nothing helped. I also used Ubuntu 14 and downloaded steam and it worked fine but once I changed to 16 it doesn't work.

Comment: Post the command you used and the full terminal output because it sounds like you've already installed it.

Comment: hpersniper@hpersniper-ms-7817:~$ sudo apt-get install steam
[sudo] password for hpersniper: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
steam:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: @HyperSniper As with any other software in Ubuntu, you search it in the Dash, the first icon in the Launcher (bar on the left) by typing one or a couple of letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line states that you've already installed steam you just need to run the program.

```
Done steam:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3)
```

The following command is simply trying to reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

You can run it via the terminal or if it's easier just type steam in the menu.

Okay well if you didn't attempt to un-install it then you should be able to find it in dash ("Search your computer") it should show up if you type steam.

To run via the terminal, well there are a few ways but for now just open it and type

```
steam
```

Then hit enter

In the future when you post code and or terminal output please format it to look like this so it's easier to read :)

```
[2016-10-02 08:45:13] uninstalled manifest found in /home/hpersniper    
/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1). 
[2016-10-02 08:45:13]   
Extracting package... 
[2016-10-02 08:45:26] Installing update...   
[2016-10-02 08:45:26] Cleaning up... 
[2016-10-02 08:45:26] Update 
complete, launching... 
[2016-10-02 08:45:26] Shutdown Running Steam on 
ubuntu 16.04 64-bit STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically [2016-10-02 
08:45:35] Startup - updater built Sep 20 2016 18:20:24 SteamUpdateUI: 
An X Error occurred X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

There are few threads open already that will help you fix any issues you have with setting up steam and or correcting issues just search around a bit! Could you mark this as an accepted answer so that your original question can be marked as solved!

Comment: How do you run it from the terminal, because I can't find it in the " Search your computer" tab thing

Comment: I ran it from terminal and it started updating and stuff but afterwards the terminal said this

Comment: [2016-10-02 08:45:13] uninstalled manifest found in /home/hpersniper/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2016-10-02 08:45:13] Extracting package...
[2016-10-02 08:45:26] Installing update...
[2016-10-02 08:45:26] Cleaning up...
[2016-10-02 08:45:26] Update complete, launching...
[2016-10-02 08:45:26] Shutdown
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-10-02 08:45:35] Startup - updater built Sep 20 2016 18:20:24
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Comment: Just to be safe could you link me to one of these threads plz.  So I know its the right thing thx :)

Comment: Please edit your question and add information about your hardware, especially the graphics card, and whether or not you installed or tried to install proprietary drivers and which ones and how have you installed, if applicable? There's no one-size-fits-all for your case.

Comment: Don't edit your question when ones regarding this already exist.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/617358/problem-starting-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04-64-bit  this is and has been a well known issue for quite a well you can even find info for this on the official steam website :)