# Steam Not Loading

Tags: games, steam

When I try to open Steam via terminal I get this:

```
bossbmm@BossBMM:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-10-12 11:06:41] Startup - updater built Sep 20 2016 18:20:24
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Please help me I need to play Rocket League

Comment: Try moving the directory `~/.steam` To another place and restart Steam, it should update and may solve it. May not though.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run these comands:

```
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

<sup>These commands were taken from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/691489/518562) answer, and the poster of that answer took them from an [UbuntuForums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275526) thread, and the author of that post took them from somewhere else...</sup>

Comment: Those instructions most likely came from [ArchWiki Steam Troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Troubleshooting), which have since been modified.  That and [Game-Specific Troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Game-specific_troubleshooting) are both great resources to fix Steam issues.