# How do I setup Steam on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: steam, 16.10

I recently setup a new pc with I3 processor and 8GB of RAM with 2TB HDD, I am brand new to Ubuntu and would like to download and install Steam.  I downloaded it but when I open it, it doesn't open, the icon loads on dock then disappears after some time.  Please help.

Comment: Make sure you got the right file. It should be named steam_latest.deb.

Comment: I had the same problem. After launching steam from the Terminal and copying to google I found this workaround: http://askubuntu.com/questions/617358/problem-starting-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04-64-bit
You maybe have to repeat the steps again after an update.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused and it still is not working, I downloaded steam straight from their website and it isnt working, I tried to remove it from Software store and it wont do that either.  At this point I am lost.  I just want to download steam and play some games.