# Steam will not launch on 64-bit 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xorg, 64-bit, steam

I have run: `steam` (after installing it from the official Trusty repos) and while the download updater window pops up, after this updater is finished with the download it gives the error:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/fusion809/.steam/steam’: Is a directory
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/fusion809/.steam/bin’: Is a directory
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2017-03-16 20:11:21] Startup - updater built Mar 13 2017 20:55:20
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1489442219)
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Is there a package I'm missing (that for some reason was not installed when I ran: `sudo apt-get install steam` to install Steam), or?

Oh and I have tried following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/691489/93125), namely running:

```
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

and then tried re-launching Steam. This did not fix this error. Also in accordance with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/730306/93125) I've added to near the start of `$HOME/.steam/steam.sh`:

```
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6'
export DISPLAY=:0
```

and that didn't fix it. In fact it introduced further errors likely due to the fact that `'` causes the `$LIB` variable not to be expanded. Plus running `echo $LIB` in a terminal returns `/usr/lib` so I think what was intended in that answer was:

```
export LD_PRELOAD="$LIB/libstdc++.so.6"
export DISPLAY=:0
```

but that also did not fix, or even alter the error in a positive way (as `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6` does not exist on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation, `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` do exist, however). Setting LD_PRELOAD to either of these paths does not fix the error either, merely adds lines of:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

or:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

to the error message. To try and help you help me I have also run:

```
LD_DEBUG=libs steam > steam_debug.log 2>&1
```

and [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fusion809/debian-scripts/9a069b5/Shell/steam_debug.log) is the `steam_debug.log` I got.

Comment: Didn't think it was relevant, but I've already tried that. Besides deleting it again only causes it to re-run the Steam updater (downloading all that data [which is 340 MB, btw] again), rofl.

Comment: Sure does, mate. I thought of deleting that folder as soon as I saw that part of the error message, don't worry you're not the only one to notice that error.

Comment: What if you run `steam.real`?

Comment: Just ran it (hasn't finished yet, I'll let ya know when it does) and it's re-downloading the 340 MB update.

Comment: From the command-line I got the error: `[2017-03-16 21:24:37] uninstalled manifest found in /home/fusion809/.steam/steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2017-03-16 21:24:37] Error: Failed to load package manifest.` and a window pops up with the error: `Fatal Error: failed to load libsteam.so`.