# Steam not launching after switching Graphics Card?

Tags: graphics, ati, games, steam

I recently purchased and installed an **AMD Sapphire R7 4GB 240**. Ubuntu automatically switched to some Open-Source Drivers named Gallium 0.4 on AMD OLAND.

For some reason Steam is not able to launch anymore. I tried opening it from command line and this error came up:

```
Running Steam on Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit

STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1440016726)

libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so

libGL error: driver pointer missing

libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi

libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so

libGL error: driver pointer missing

libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi

libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

(Steam used to work properly)

I believe Steam was not able to find Official Drivers, since I did not install them, which I am unable to find. A DVD with those drivers was included, but it said "Windows XP,Vista,7,8". Not Mac or anything.

Is anybody who knows what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I started it up with the help of irc.ubuntu.com with this article: https://wirejungle.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/how-to-fix-broken-steam-linux-client-with-radeon-graphics-driver-workaround/ ... but I can't start up any game at all

**Second Edit:** You can also tell me how to run games on Steam while running this following command:

LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 DISPLAY=:0 steam

**EDIT 3:** @SachinKamath told me to re-install Steam from the command line, after deleting Steam. (She was right, even though a Steam Launcher problem seems to appear)

But the following error appears if I run it on command line:
Erm.. I got one problem..

Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit

STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically

[2015-08-26 17:07:59] Startup - updater built Aug 19 2015 11:27:40

SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for 
operation)

(Was it a corrupted download? Perhaps?)

Comment: try restarting your display manager using `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: I will try. P.S. I am not using fglxr since I cannot login. Login Loops... not even with CTRL + Alt + F1/F2, since it leads to a black screen. Empty.

EDIT: @SachinKamath Your trick didn't work.. Steam seems to not be able to find some files.

Comment: How did you install steam?  You downloaded the deb file from their website?  If it's so, remove it and then do a `sudo apt-get install steam`

Comment: It will automatically install the required librarie and packages required for you.

Comment: Should I delete the .steam folder too? @Sachin

Comment: Oh my lord! It worked! Thank you so much @Sachin, Now I can finally play Counter strike.. :D Keep up the great work

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Happy gaming ;)

Comment: Wait.. this didn't go as expected. Read my edit of the post. @SachinKamath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution is to remove the .deb file installed from the Steam website and do `sudo apt-get install steam` as it automatically installs the required libraries and packages required for the proper functioning of Steam.

Edit : Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/614458#614458) answer to fix the Integer parameter error that throws up.

Comment: Erm.. I got one problem.. 

Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2015-08-26 17:07:59] Startup - updater built Aug 19 2015 11:27:40
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Comment: Perhaps it was corrupted download? Let me try again..

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: This is not my problem anymore.  I got a new error, check the EDIT 3 on my post

Comment: This one is a graphic card specific error. You should probably open a new thread on this so that others can help you out. I tried my best to help you but my knowledge of the X drivers is limited. After opening a new thread, do post the link here. Cheers mate :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/666326/an-x-error-occured-after-attempting-to-launch-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04 Thanks for your help :)