# Steam won't open (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: nvidia, steam

I'm trying to install steam on my new pc but it just won't run.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit  
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically  
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)  
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found  
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I've tried some solutions I've find on the Internet (like [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/614458#614458) or [Steam won't open in Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689598/steam-wont-open-in-ubuntu-15-10)). Most of them seem to say that it's a problem with steam trying us old libraries and that some files should be removed.

I've tried it and it still doesn't work.
Here is the content of the folder ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

```
libfreetype.so.6        libXau.so.6.0.0    libXinerama.so.1  
libfreetype.so.6.8.0    libxcb.so.1        libXinerama.so.1.0.0  
libstdc++.so.6.0.18     libxcb.so.1.1.0    libXrandr.so.2  
libstdc++.so.6.disable  libXdmcp.so.6      libXrandr.so.2.2.0  
libX11.so.6             libXdmcp.so.6.0.0  libXrender.so.1  
libX11.so.6.3.0         libXext.so.6       libXrender.so.1.3.0  
libXau.so.6             libXext.so.6.4.0
```

As you can see, I've tried renaming libstdc++.so.6 because it worked for some people out there and I've also removed libgcc_s.so.1 in ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ but the problem remains.

I have a GTX 1070 and I manually installed NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run from the nvidia website (I don't know if that matters)

I'm starting to feel desperate. How good is a gaming pc if you can't run steam :'(
Anyone has any solution ? I don't want to have to go back to windows ><

Comment: can you please open a terminal and enter 'glxinfo | egrep "(OpenGL vendor string|OpenGL renderer string)"'? This would show us hopefully, which card and driver you are currently REALLY using.

Comment: Ok, it says


    OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
    OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2

Answer (score 0):

Ok I removed steam and then used

```
sudo apt-get install steam-launcher
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

It downloaded an update and now when I run steam it tells me

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

and asks for my password. Then

```
 .........................................................................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

And then when I press return, a windows shows up saying

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
```

Then I click "ok" and terminal shows

```
/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 444: no match: ssfn*
user@user-desktop:~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-lin
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to make it work :D

I basically reinstalled ubuntu and instead of gettind nvidia's drivers from their website I did it from the repository

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```