# Unable to start steam Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: games, steam, mate

I've installed steam through the software boutique, but whenever I try to launch it, it fails.  I get the steam popup window saying that it is updating steam and checking for updates, but it crashed before anything else happens.  I've tried the solutions posted here ([Steam won't open in Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689598/steam-wont-open-in-ubuntu-15-10)) but it doesn't solve my problem.

Here is the output when I try to run steam in a terminal.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/whenke/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
awk: /home/whenke/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "topmenu-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 80: saw unknown, expected number
[1010/124635:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[1010/124635:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160920182018)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1474395618)
[1010/124635:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160920182018)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1474415843)
assert_20161010124634_1.dmp[5572]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20161010124634_1.dmp
assert_20161010124634_1.dmp[5572]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20161010124634_1.dmp[5572]: response: CrashID=bp-081206d1-dd5d-479d-8672-aa9622161010
assert_20161010124634_1.dmp[5572]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20161010124634_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-081206d1-dd5d-479d-8672-aa9622161010''
/home/whenke/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 713:  5543 Bus error               (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/812114/15003 may help.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the same thing still happens

Comment: A couple of things you can try. 1. `STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam`. 2. `Exec=env LC_ALL=C steam $@` 3. `ldd steam | grep found` and look at any libs that are missing. Install the missing libs