# I'm new to Ubuntu and can't figure out why Steam won't work

Tags: drivers, steam, 15.10

At first it would open, I was using wine to run it or something like that, like a forum I had read told me, but couldn't play any games due to some drivers issues I believe. Then I tried updating them but when I went to the system update area to update the drivers, there were no available updates to be had. Some more time and troubleshooting had passed and now Steam simply won't even open, saying `FATAL ERROR: failed to load steamuo.si` and I have literally no idea as to what I have to do. Please help!

Steam in terminal:

```
[2015-10-27 00:43:49] Startup - updater built May  5 2015 12:15:27
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2015-10-27 00:43:49] Checking for update on startup
[2015-10-27 00:43:49] Checking for available updates...
[2015-10-27 00:43:49] Download complete.
[2015-10-27 00:43:49] uninstalled manifest found in /home/joey/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2015-10-27 00:43:49] Found pending update
[2015-10-27 00:43:49] Installing update...
[2015-10-27 00:43:49] Extracting package...
[2015-10-27 00:44:08] Installing update...
[2015-10-27 00:44:09] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to create directory ./steam/cached
```

lspci | grep VGA in terminal:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
```

After "LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam"

```
[2015-10-27 19:43:54] Startup - updater built May  5 2015 12:15:27
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2015-10-27 19:43:54] Checking for update on startup
[2015-10-27 19:43:54] Checking for available updates...
[2015-10-27 19:43:55] Download complete.
[2015-10-27 19:43:55] uninstalled manifest found in /home/joey/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2015-10-27 19:43:55] Found pending update
[2015-10-27 19:43:55] Installing update...
[2015-10-27 19:43:55] Extracting package...
[2015-10-27 19:44:13] Installing update...
[2015-10-27 19:44:14] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to create directory ./steam/cached
[2015-10-27 19:44:14] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to process ./steam
[2015-10-27 19:44:14] Failed to apply update, reverting...
[2015-10-27 19:44:14] Verifying installation...
[2015-10-27 19:44:14] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2015-10-27 19:44:14] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/joey/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2015-10-27 19:44:14] Verification complete
[2015-10-27 19:44:14] Downloading update...
[2015-10-27 19:44:14] Checking for available updates...
[2015-10-27 19:44:15] Download complete.
[2015-10-27 19:44:15] Extracting package...
[2015-10-27 19:44:33] Installing update...
[2015-10-27 19:44:34] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to create directory ./steam/cached
[2015-10-27 19:44:34] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to process ./steam
[2015-10-27 19:44:34] Failed to apply update, reverting...
[2015-10-27 19:44:50] Shutdown
```

output of command "cd ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32"

.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32$

After "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steamui.so"

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf778b000)
libtier0_s.so => not found
libvstdlib_s.so => not found
libv8.so => not found
libvideo.so => not found
libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => not found
libXtst.so.6 => not found
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf63b0000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0xf63a2000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf638d000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf6242000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0xf61af000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf6150000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf6028000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf5b32000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf5b29000)
libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0xf5ad0000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xf5aa7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf5a59000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf5a54000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf58dd000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf58c0000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf778c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf5705000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf56f8000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf56d3000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf56aa000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0xf568f000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf568b000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xf5687000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xf566c000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xf5666000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0xf5662000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0xf565e000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0xf5655000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0xf5652000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf564b000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0xf5639000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xf562f000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf55bb000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf54fb000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xf54f6000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xf54e8000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xf54c1000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0xf537f000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xf51bd000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xf51a6000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xf5154000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf5111000)
libjson-c.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2 (0xf5104000)
libpulsecommon-6.0.so => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-6.0.so (0xf507f000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0xf5025000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf5007000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf5003000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf4ffb000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0xf4ff7000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xf4fe5000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0xf4fda000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xf4fd6000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf4f28000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xf4e75000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf4e49000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0xf4e45000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xf4e3a000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf4e1e000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0xf4df6000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf4ddd000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0xf4d79000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0xf4d6f000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0xf4ce2000)
libwrap.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0xf4cd8000)
libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0xf4c5f000)
libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0xf4c58000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0xf4c3a000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0xf4c31000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0xf4c0b000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0xf4b5a000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0xf4b3f000)
libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0xf4ade000)
libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0xf4a4f000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xf4a3a000)
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0xf4a31000)
libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0xf4a04000)
```

joey@Chet:~$

After sudo apt-get install libstdc++6

```
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
```

fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core gnome-exe-thumbnailer libcapi20-3
  libcapi20-3:i386 libexif12:i386 libgd3:i386 libgif4:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386
  libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libice6:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libltdl7:i386
  libodbc1 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libsane:i386 libsm6:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386
  libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 libvpx2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
  libxt6:i386 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 p11-kit-modules:i386 unixodbc
  Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Comment: You could, for example add essensial info to the question, such as the graphics card model and the driver version. Please refrain from vague statements like "...some drivers issues I believe".

Comment: Have you tried to install it with the [software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steam-launcher/) ? You don't need to use Wine IIRC.

Comment: I have and I believe that's how I encountered the issue with the whole "FATAL ERROR" thing

Comment: I would if I knew, to be quite honest I'm not very tech savy and don't really know how to find out what they are on ubuntu

Comment: Well,  what is your ubuntu version and graphic card ("lspci | grep VGA" in terminal) ? And can you run steam in terminal and post the result ?

Comment: Try something like this: `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA` in a terminal window.

Comment: After "lspci | grep VGA": 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

Comment: The text after running steam in the terminal was too long, so i'll be putting it as an edit in the post. Thank you for your attention, and help thus far by the way! I appreciate your time!

Comment: Also, my Ubuntu version is 15.10 I believe

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, then I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04). I'm also running 15.10 and these commands fixed me right up.

```
mv ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1{,.disable}
mv ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6{,.disable}
```

Best of luck to ya!

Comment: Both commands say "no such file or directory"

Comment: I made a change to the commands. Give it a shot and let us know how it works out.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying and pasting in a terminal:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

This command will help us identify if it is the dependency keeping Steam from opening. The terminal will have to remain open while using Steam so it's not exactly the solution we're after. Let me know your outcome.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30977/discussion-on-answer-by-kofsurp-im-new-to-ubuntu-and-cant-figure-out-why-steam).