# libGL error when starting Steam on Ubuntu 15.10 32-bit

Tags: drivers, steam, amd-graphics, opengl

Can't launch Steam - it just won't start. I tried to open it from the terminal and I got this

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1447125378)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Note that my laptop has AMD video card which steals 400 Mb from RAM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 0):

Well, now Steam opens. In the morning I switched to all proprietary drivers it still didn't open but now in the terminal was trying to install a library to steam or something which took forever so I killed the process. But in the evening I tried to open again and it works fine.