# Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, software-installation, 15.10, 64-bit, steam

I'm trying to install Steam on Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit.

When I run steam, I get the following output:

```
username@computer:~/Desktop$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I've seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04), but I've not been able to apply those answers to my situation.  I'm dealing with radeon drivers, to start.

Answer (score 4):

Run the following in a shell:

```
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6'
export DISPLAY=:0
```

And steam should start to work:

```
steam
```

This worked for me. ([source](https://wirejungle.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/how-to-fix-broken-steam-linux-client-with-radeon-graphics-driver-workaround/))