# Steam won't start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xorg, steam, 16.04, 32-bit

After it was reinstalled, updates downloaded but it won’t start even from the terminal. This is the error message it gives:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 32-bit  
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically  
[2016-04-25 09:12:35] Startup - updater built Mar 31 2016 19:10:48  
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred  
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Comment: Bug on official Ubuntu tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/steam/+bug/1527669 I solved a similar problem by downgrading the nvidia driver: https://askubuntu.com/questions/893922/ubuntu-16-04-gives-x-error-of-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-o/994299#994299

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've had the same problem, which I was able to solve following instructions from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275526:

> This is a problem with steam and ubuntu 15.04. Steam bundles old libs
>   and are colliding with mesa drivers, that is also why closed drivers
>   aren't seeing this problem.
>
> There is a [open bug](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3801) in steam github the workaround for now is to
>   remove the old lib version, at least until valve fix the issue in
>   their startup script or similar. So enter this folders and do this
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
> mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
> cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
> ```
>
> It worked for me... but please note that if some game required that
>   old lib from the steam runtime, it may crash (that is why should be
>   valve fixing this)

Edit:
The steps in the thread were already quoted from [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/614458#614458), so you can go there for more details in case these instructions are not enough for you to solve your problem.

Comment: For the both mv command, I got: `gnu: No such file or directory`. Why?

Comment: @CasperLI They may be in a different directory. Try going to the path from  Nick's answer (http://askubuntu.com/a/778521/514190) and renaming libstdc++.so.6 in your favourite file manager. Or just find the file:

Comment: missing command from comment above: ```find ~/.steam -name "libstdc++.so.6" ```

Comment: This did not work on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Restarting fixed it... I had closed anything in `ps aux | grep steam`. It must run something else. Still a bummer that it seems to crash when offline.

Answer (score 5):

The answer above was correct for me although the path to the files weren't quite the same when I was trying to get steam to run on 16.04 the path I needed was

```
~/.steam/bin/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

Also after updating the first time I had to do this again or it still wouldn't update.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing libstdc++, first investigate whether this error is caused by ambiguous libGL symbolic links.

Refer to my other answer that also worked for me fixing this problem
https://askubuntu.com/a/903488/364084

I am going to paste the content here:

If you are using nvidia driver, sometimes you will see that libGL.so.1 points to ambiguous libGL provided by both mesa and nvidia. To test this, you can run this command

```
$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so
```

The output was something like:

```
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
    libftgl.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libftgl.so.2
    libcogl.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
    libQtOpenGL.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4
    libQtOpenGL.so.4 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libOpenGL.so.0
    libOpenGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libOpenGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-378/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGL.so
    libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-378/libGL.so
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-378/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libEGL.so
    libEGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-378/libEGL.so
```

Now I just needed to remove the library provided by mesa and everything worked perfectly.

```
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
```

Answer (score 0):

balver's solve worked, however, the directory is slightly different than what was posted. Here's the command sequence as I typed it:

```
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

Answer (score -1):

`sudo apt-get install libnvidia-gl-390:i386`

ref:
https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/0/3140616601474785172/