# Trying to run steam on kubuntu 16.04 but it crashes immediately after launch

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, steam

I'm having an issue with steam whenever I launch the program it tries to load but abruptly crashes a few seconds after I launch it. I just ran it via the terminal and this is what I got

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Now from what I'm seeing, I'm guessing that there is an issue with the open source amd driver and steam in the sense that they don't like each other for whatever reason and sense fglrx is no longer available the open source driver is my only option.

Can anyone confirm that this is, in fact, an issue with the driver, and if it is is there a work around?

Comment: Did you download and install Steam manually from their website, or use the version in the Ubuntu software repositories (`sudo apt install steam`)? The latter tends to work better

Comment: I downloaded the .deb from their website directly

Comment: Try installing the official Ubuntu version instead, using the terminal command in my previous comment. (You can open a terminal by pressing Alt-Ctrl-T). Let us know how it works.

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: A better duplicate would be [Steam not opening in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](/q/771032) if you consider the error messages.

Answer (score 2):

When I created this thread I saw similar questions but after spending the last four and half hours digging through the forums I found this [Steam won't start on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762219/steam-wont-start-on-ubuntu-16-04) and I was able to fix my issue by doing the following

```
enter cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

Once I did this it worked fine, the issue was as I thought an issue with the open source driver it seems valve needs to fix this issue by tweaking a few things on their end but for the time being this should help anyone with this issue, I'll check this as answer tomorrow!