# Steam: libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam

If I click the desktop app of "Steam", nothing happens.

Running `steam` in terminal produces the following:

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

What's interesting is that if I change my GPU driver to `xorg`, it works perfectly.

What can I do to make it work? It stopped working after the latest steam update(36 hours ago).

I tried uninstalling nvidia - `sudo apt-get remove nvidia*` and re-installing the driver, but with no luck.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Ubuntu 16.04+**
For anyone still getting same error, if you are using nvidia driver, sometimes you will see that libGL.so.1 points to ambiguous libGL provided by both mesa and nvidia. To test this, you can run this command

```
$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so
```

The output was something like:

```
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
    libftgl.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libftgl.so.2
    libcogl.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
    libQtOpenGL.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4
    libQtOpenGL.so.4 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libOpenGL.so.0
    libOpenGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libOpenGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-378/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libGL.so
    libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-378/libGL.so
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-378/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-378/libEGL.so
    libEGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-378/libEGL.so
```

Now I just needed to remove the library provided by mesa and everything worked perfectly.

```
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
```

**Update:**
This issue no longer exists from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Man, you deserve a huge cookie.

Comment: on debian 9, I removed this one and worked, but no mention to "mesa", however, "dpkg -S libGL.so.1" give a tip which one you should remove. So: 

rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 

And enjoy your cookie :)

Comment: Yep, basically you need to remove libGL.so.1 from wherever it is in your system.

Comment: This is correct; at first I thought that it would be better to remove the package (libgl1-mesa-glx) that libGL.so.1 belongs to, but as it happens, this is a requirement of the Steam package. So just remove libGL.so.1 (which should be a symbolic link anyway).

Comment: I don't have a `mesa` folder in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`. I tried removing `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1`, and steam said: `You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libGL.so.1`

Comment: This was an error scenario that caused due to conflicts between mesa and nvidia. If you don't have one or the other, then probably the reason is something different. If you are using ubuntu 18.04, this issue no longer exists.

Comment: I had the same problem in CentOS 7. (thanks @ZobayerHasan saved a lot of time). Removing the default libGL libs solved the issue. But is there a better solution without deleting the default library?

Comment: This issue persists on 18.10

Comment: @QkiZ, Interesting, cause I did fresh install of 18.04 and steam, with nvidia drivers. And this problem did not occur. Somehow 18.10 re-introduced the problem?

Comment: Yes. I resolved it by resolution from https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5884#issuecomment-437690163

Comment: After updating Linux Mint from 18 to 19 i had this issue. I had to remove /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 Thank you Zobayer Hasan for your help!

Comment: Removing /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 lets the Steam launch somewhat but then complains that this is missing, if it is found then the launch crashes to "An X Error occurred" :(

Comment: @NikoNyrh You should only remove it when it is redundant, otherwise probably have to look into other solutions.

Comment: It seems that my issue is related to CUDA 10 not shipping with x86 version of some drivers(?) which Steam requires. I don't have the relevant links at hand atm.

Comment: This issue persists on 19.10 `sudo rm -rf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1` fix it

Answer (score 32):

In my situation I had to install the i386 NVIDIA drivers.  It worked thereafter.

> sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-440:i386

Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks bro! This works for me in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I was able to get away with just `sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-440`

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading to `nvidia-driver-440`! I didn't realize that my `glxgears` binary was 32-bit at first.

Comment: I play WoW using Lutris, and after upgrading from 390 to 450 to support my new GeForce GTX 1660 on Mint 19.3, I was getting the same error in my WINE console output:
```"libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast```
The error was resolved by installing `libnvidia-gl-450:i386` which was not selected by default for some reason.

Comment: It says `Depends: libnvidia-gl-450:i386`, but installing `libnvidia-gl-450:i386` threatens to remove `cuda-10-1 cuda-demo-suite-10-1 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-450 cuda-runtime-10-1 libnvidia-gl-450
  libnvidia-ifr1-450 nvidia-driver-450` but i need cuda 10.1.

As Cuda 11 and Cuda 10.2 is not supported by many libraries I daily use. 
Want to use steam and Cuda.

Comment: Thanks heaps.  I needed to: `apt install libnvidia-gl-460:i386` on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This fixed an issue for me.  I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 within WSL2 (Windows 10) where the host machine has an NVidia GPU.

Comment: FYI, the number at the end needs to match the version of the nvidia driver you are using. You can check with `nvidia-smi | grep -i version`

Answer (score 17):

## Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Has Same Error

In Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) under Windows 10 there the file `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1` does not exist. Instead there is the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1` seems to replace it. However if you delete the replacement file the library doesn't work at all.

## Rename library then rename back solves problem

If you rename the file and then rename it back the errors disappear and it works a lot faster:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:/mnt/e/etc$ lock-screen-timer
Linux version 4.4.0-43-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) ) #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:/mnt/e/etc$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so
        libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
        libcogl.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
        libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
        libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
        libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libEGL.so.1
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:/mnt/e/etc$ sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1': No such file or directory
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:/mnt/e/etc$ sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.ORIGINAL
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:/mnt/e/etc$ lock-screen-timer
Linux version 4.4.0-43-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) ) #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014
/usr/bin/zenity: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:/mnt/e/etc$ sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.ORIGINAL /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:/mnt/e/etc$ lock-screen-timer
Linux version 4.4.0-43-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) ) #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:/mnt/e/etc$
```

I verified the change is persistent, ie close the WSL terminal window and open a new window.

## Quick Fix From Comments

In comment below it is suggested to try https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450299/6929343:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

For a quick test, run:

```
glxinfo -B | grep renderer
```

> **NOTE:** I haven't tested this solution.

## What's Using the Library?

The library is used by `yad` in the [lock-screen-timer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837078/application-that-will-lock-screen-after-a-set-amount-of-time-for-ubuntu/837115#837115) bash script upgraded with hybrid support for WSL in addition to Ubuntu. Yad is a fork of `Zenity` which is why you see the Zenity-like `Gtk-Message:` reference in the third error message above.

Here's what the `yad` window looks like in Ubuntu (in WSL it's slightly different):

[image: Lock Screen Timer]

Comment: This didn't work for me - although I'm not using lock-screen-timer

Comment: `lock-screen-timer` is just an example of a script that calls the GUI. You could use `gedit`.

Comment: Sure, I realize. My point is that my application (`rqt`) might be invoking the GUI in a different way, which might be why it still fails after trying your fix

Comment: Hm. For me gnome-terminal throws the same warning, but even without renaming anything, the warning is gone when starting a second instance of gnome-terminal. Isn't that the case maybe for your "solution" too?

Comment: This did not work for me as well

Comment: I don't even have mesa folder in my WSL2

Comment: @Praytic The answer was posted for WSL (version 1). I haven't had time to reboot and test WSL2 yet.

Comment: For WSL you need to run `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1`. See the dedicated question about WSL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61831052/how-do-i-run-opengl-programs-using-wsl-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: @Aaron Thank you for the comment. I rolled it up into the answer and I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a nvidia driver issue, according to a [steam-for-linux issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5884#issuecomment-437690163).

In my case, I installed [SuperTuxKart](https://supertuxkart.net/Main_Page) through `flapak`, when I ran it, I met following errors:

```
..:: Antarctica Rendering Engine 2.0 ::..
Linux 4.15.0-52-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 4 22:49:08 UTC 2019 x86_64
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

My solution is:

1. Check nvidia driver on my system

`ubuntu-drivers devices`

It has `nvidia-driver-430` installed already.

2. According to the [steam-for-linux issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5884#issuecomment-437690163) issue, install  `nvidia-driver-418` to replace `nvidia-driver-430`

`sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-418`

It prompted that it lack dependency of `libnvidia-compute-418`, so just install `libnvidia-compute-418` first.

`sudo apt install libnvidia-compute-418`

then

`sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-418`

3. Reboot system.

Then I ran  [SuperTuxKart](https://supertuxkart.net/Main_Page), it worked.

Comment: This helped me in using Target3001 in wine.

Comment: I am on AMD graphics facing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was that I had enabled some CUDA apt sources that had installed the 440 nvidia driver and tools. Once I disabled that and installed the then latest version of nvidia driver (435), it installed everything else needed and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions that worked for me:

- Ubuntu 20.04:
  `sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-440`
  (without `:i386`)
- WSL2 Windows 10: run XServer with -nowgl (and -ac):
  `"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :0 -multiwindow -clipboard -nowgl -ac`
  #see https://askubuntu.com/a/1394781/498339