# Steam doesn't start with nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 16.04. No error shown

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam

If i have the default nvidia drivers (nvidia-384) steam doesn't start. If I run `steam` in a terminal i get this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
[2018-04-05 09:36:52] Startup - updater built Apr  2 2018 15:23:43

Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check

[2018-04-05 09:36:52] Checking for update on startup
[2018-04-05 09:36:52] Checking for available updates...
[2018-04-05 09:36:53] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1522709999, installed version 1522709999
[2018-04-05 09:36:53] Nothing to do
[2018-04-05 09:36:53] Verifying installation...
[2018-04-05 09:36:53] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2018-04-05 09:36:54] Verification complete
```

And close. Nothing more happen.

If I have the "x.org x server - Nouveau" driver it run fine.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove steam
sudo apt-get purge steam
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Steam && rm -rf ~/.steam
```

and then

```
sudo apr-get install steam
```

and the  problem doesn't fix.

I don't know what to do. Thanks.

**UPDATE and FIX**

The problem was solved doing this:

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so

sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
```

I found th solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834254/steam-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl-error-failed-t).

It looks that this is a common problem with nvidia drivers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to http://steampowered.com and downloading a more recent version of steam directly from them. You'll end up with a .deb file; if you double click it in the file manager it should open up in the "Software" program. It will allow you to install from there and should download all the dependencies that steam requires.

Comment: Now show some errors. I update the post with the solution that I found. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that one. Thanks for letting us all know.