# run windows game on wine with nvidia propetary driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, wine, 19.04

I installed nvidia propetary driver directly downloaded from nvidia website. Then I installed wine-stable from official repository and all stuff to run 3d application under wine and I got this error:

```
0009:fixme:system:SystemParametersInfoW Unimplemented action: 110 
(SPI_GETSHOWIMEUI)
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33e744,0x00000000), stub!
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  203
  Current serial number in output stream:  202
```

My pc is Ryzen 7 2700 + Nvidia GTX 1050ti + 16GB Ram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steam: libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834254/steam-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl-error-failed-t)

Answer (score 0):

Try lutris:
https://lutris.net/

It installs wine and all needed components automatically.

Try installing nvidia driver from ppa repository:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux