# Ubuntu18.04 steam libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found and libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, steam, opengl

Probably the same problem as [Steam: libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834254/steam-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl-error-failed-t) but none of the solution there works for me.

This happens after I updated my driver, the old and working one probable 384.

I installed the 440 from .run file to use cuda 10 and [detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2), which is worked.

The problem is that I can't run steam anymore, run it via terminal give me this

```
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2019-11-09 01:36:34] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Previously, if I switch to 384 I can use steam normally but for some reason it suddenly give me `a start job is running for hold` and I have to re-install the driver to be able to boot my PC properly, now both the `apt install` and `software and update` have only 390 and 410. And I can't open steam anymore.

I tried `sudo apt install libnvidia-gl` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I disabled my graphics driver and installed it again, and it seemed to work just fin. See https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, with Quadro NVIDIA graphics.

Comment: It's so long ago that I don't really remember much. But no it wasn't about being unable to install the driver. The driver worked fine and I was able ti train neural networks with GPU.

Comment: The problem was lack of update/upgrade to the point that some dependencies randomly stopped working.