# Steam won't launch on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, games, steam, nvidia-geforce

Recently reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 and in the process on reinstalling some applications, one of which is Steam. I've tried both steam deb release and the native application software installer. When trying to use the installer, I get the message: `Unable to install "Steam Installer": The following packages have unmet packages:` without showing the packages needed to install. After installing the deb release and running `steam`, I am greated with this error message:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/tbick00/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2021-06-26 18:50:56] Startup - updater built Jun  8 2021 22:23:36
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  45
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  46
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-06-26 18:50:56] Loading cached metrics from disk         
(/home/tbick00/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2021-06-26 18:50:56] Failed to load cached hosts file (File     
'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2021-06-26 18:50:56] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm     
steamglobal
[2021-06-26 18:50:56] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 
'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
[2021-06-26 18:50:56] Checking for update on startup
[2021-06-26 18:50:56] Checking for available updates...
[2021-06-26 18:50:56] Downloading manifest:     
http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
[2021-06-26 18:50:57] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version     
1623193086, installed version 1623193086, existing pending version 0
[2021-06-26 18:50:57] Nothing to do
[2021-06-26 18:50:57] Verifying installation...
[2021-06-26 18:50:57] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-06-26 18:50:57] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6501165
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:3466): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path:     
"adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier `direction',     
expected character `}'
(steam:3466): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: 
"adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant     
"normal_entry", expected valid string constant
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  51
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  50
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  52
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20210626185056_1.dmp[3531]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20210626185056_1.dmp
/home/tbick00/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 772:  3466 Segmentation fault      
(core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER $DEBUGGER_ARGS "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
tbick00@Bickham-Linux-Dsk:~$ assert_20210626185056_1.dmp[3531]: Finished uploading 
minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20210626185056_1.dmp[3531]: response: CrashID=bp-bc5586f7-7138-4907-b501- 
266622210626
assert_20210626185056_1.dmp[3531]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20210626185056_1.dmp'', 
upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-bc5586f7-7138-4907-b501-266622210626''
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have searched online for a while and the majority of proposed solutions are to download and install mesa packages, and rename or remove particular lib files and directories; none of those solutions have worked for me. If anyone can look into this crash report of sorts and help me diagnose the issue I would be very happy. Thanks so much!

Comment: Have a look at 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/834254/steam-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl-error-failed-t

might be of some help to you

Comment: Thank you so much! Found a solution that works! I appreciate the direction!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Steam: libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834254/steam-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl-error-failed-t)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that installing a particular package is what can solve this issue. I used the command `sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-440:i386` and steam opened from the gui and command line.