# Steam Errors within selected Nvidia GPU on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.04, steam

I'm installing nvidia-prime and select nvidia by the default. 
(I have proprietary nvidia-361).
Then when i trying to launch Steam i'm getting those errors:

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-05-28 19:45:46] Startup - updater built Apr 29 2016 22:18:33
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

and that's it in here. Let's go there:

```
$ ./steam.sh
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
[2016-05-28 19:50:48] Startup - updater built Apr 29 2016 22:18:33
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1461972496)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

My Steam installed in /home/$USER/.steam
and i just run him by the ./steam.sh

From these
[Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04)
only work that:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib32/nvidia-361/:/usr/lib/nvidia-361/" steam
```

But! When i just switch graphic to Intel (prime-select intel, and relog) i can easy run Steam from a command on a Desktop. The command is simple:

```
/home/$USER/.steam/steam.sh %U
```

But! I need run it like that only when i'm activate the Nvidia.

So, how i can create a new command on a desktop and run steam on nvidia without a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Paste this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Steam with NVidia
Exec=LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib32/nvidia-361/:/usr/lib/nvidia-361/" steam
Terminal=false
Icon=steam
Type=Application
Categories=Game;
```

...into a file called `steamnvidia.desktop` and put it in the directory `/usr/local/share/applications`. You should see other `.desktop` files in there that will have a similar structure to this. Make sure this file is executable (`chmod +x steamnvidia.desktop`), and you will probably need root powers to get it into the folder above.

Now search in dash (may take a couple times searching for it to reindex) "Steam with NVidia", as the `Name=` line in the file shows.

If you have to change the execution line for whatever reason, change the `Exec=` line to what you need.

You *might* also need to give the full `steam` path, not sure if environmental variables will work in desktop files.