# Successfully installing Steam on Ubuntu 16.04 64Bit

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, 64-bit, steam

This question has been discussed so many times already but I've tried all those answers I still can't seem to get Steam running on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

My system: i7 6700k, NVIDIA GTX 1070, Asus z170 Motherboard. I've installed proprietary Nvidia drivers (367.27)

I installed steam by downloading from steam website (first tried with repository version but that didn't work so I used website version) and I don't know how to remove/uninstall apps installed with sudo dpkg -i or similar method.

Upon running steam from command line I get:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/wisemonkey/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/wisemonkey/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I'm trying to follow [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04) but it seems path mentioned in the mostly accepted answer has been changed, I've mesa related packages installed.

If this helps:

```
DISPLAY=:0 glxinfo | grep -i direct
```

Outputs:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: unable to open display :0
```

So I need to use

```
DISPLAY=:1 glxinfo | grep -i direct
```

And output:

```
direct rendering: Yes (with lot more info)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I don't like the way this turned out (I don't understand how to replicate the results).

However here is in general what I've done, I tried re-installing NVIDIA drivers (while running X) obviously that failed, at this point I already has 32 bit libraries installed. On next restart I got blank screen (no way to boot). I unplugged Video card and connected on-board graphics, boot went through but it gave me prompt instead of X, I installed NVIDIA drivers and said yes to 32bit libraries. Reconnected my Video card, on next boot Steam started no issues.

Comment: I don't know why you got the blank screen issue, but indeed the issue that Steam had was the missing 32bit OpenGL libraries. You can recognize that because the OpenGL driver it is trying to load is swrast_dri.so , which is the software renderer without hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I renamed the library libstdc ++ .so. 6 for `libstdc++.so.6.old` in those folders:

```
./ubuntu12_32/steam steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
./ubuntu12_32/steam steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I hope I helped.