# Steam wont open Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, steam

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and when I launch it I get an error.

```
> Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I would appreciate ANY help!

```
ii  steam:i386                                  1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3                                         i386         Valve's Steam digital software delivery system
ii  steam-launcher                              1.0.0.52                                                    all          Launcher for the Steam software distribution service
```

Comment: Possible duplicate / related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04 . Try opening a terminal (Alt-Ctrl-T) and run `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`. Other possible solutions are listed on the linked question

Comment: or see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1504046#p1504046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purge what you have installed and update your system.  I have found that a fresh install and a fresh upgrade often needs some updates.

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge steam
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt install steam
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. when I removed it it said that nothing was removing. when I launched it it said the same thing.

Comment: That might be a significant part of the problem.  If it can't be uninstalled, then the install my be problematic.  How did you originally install it?  After you attempted to remove it, did you perform a reinstall?

Comment: I installed it using the .deb file from the website, where it brought me to the "Steam-Installer". I did attempt to reinstall it but it still would not work.

Comment: That explains the error.  It has to be removed with `dpkg --remove packagename`  Try moving it that way.  Then use the commands in the answer.

Comment: @Jonathan By the way, when you remove the problem package with the command in my last message, make sure it's actually removed by running `steam` from the console. If it starts we'll have to figure out why it's not removed and get it uninstalled.  Installing it with the `apt` command might work to overwrite what's there, but removing the current failed application would be the best way to have it fully functional.

Comment: I tried all of them but it would not work still

Comment: @Jonathan When you removed steam, did you verify it was removed by trying to run it and getting an error message?  This has to be done before any of the steps in the answer.

Comment: I don't have superuser permissions so I cannot use the DPKG command. But for the other one, yes, I checked.

Comment: When I use the command it says Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'steam:i386' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

Comment: None of the other command will work without superuser permission.  All the commands are `sudo` commands.  You'll have to get the administrator to address the issue.  By the way, can you provide the command you used for installing the `*.deb` package you downloaded?

Comment: @Jonathan can you show output of `dpkg -l | egrep steam` .

Comment: I downloaded the .deb from the file and from your command I got "ii  steam:i386                                  1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3                                         i386         Valve's Steam digital software delivery system
ii  steam-launcher                              1.0.0.52                                                    all          Launcher for the Steam software distribution service
" but I will add that

Comment: The comment message is sufficient.

Comment: Can you tell me where you downloaded the *.deb package?

Comment: I got it from the official steam website. My administrator has fixed steam though so it is completely working. Thank you for your answer.