# Can't Run Steam on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: steam, 16.10

I have Googled and also check the few questions on AskUbuntu without any luck.

Here is what I get when I run `steam` in console;

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/myUser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04

Comment: Are you using the Steam version downloaded from the website, or the Steam version provided by the Ubuntu Multiverse repo? Steam versions from the website are only supported by LTS releases.

Comment: @PatrickNegus downloaded from their website. But fixed the issue for the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Found [this link](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/steam-doesnt-launch/623/14) in `[this AskUbuntu][2]` question;

Simply executed this piece of command and all went back to normal;

`find ~/.steam/root/ -name "libgpg-error.so*" -print -delete`

Thank you all for the help.