# Steam Does Not Open After Install

Tags: games, steam, 16.10

I have just installed steam using the .deb that can be downloaded from the Steam website.

After installed the .deb file attempting to launch Steam using the icon gives me no results. When trying to launch Steam from the console this is the output that I get:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/max/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I have spent some time looking around for answers but have not come up with anything that has worked for me yet. Any input would be helpful.

Comment: What about this? [Ubuntu 16.04 Steam only runs from terminal](//askubuntu.com/q/812040)

Comment: @Zanna This was a no-go. It did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Run This command in terminal bellow.

```
find $HOME/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/*/usr/lib/ \( -name "libstdc++.so.6" -o -name "libgpg-error.so.0"  -o -name "libxcb.so.1" -o -name "libgcc_s.so.1" \) -exec mv "{}" "{}.bak" \; -print
```

This an issue with the mesa drivers.

[source higuita answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/614458/462639)

Comment: I ran the command you gave, but it does not seem to have worked. Same output and issue.

    Output:   

  max@MaxsLaptop:~$ find $HOME/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/*/usr/lib/ \( -name "libstdc++.so.6" -o -name "libgpg-error.so.0"  -o -name "libxcb.so.1" -o -name "libgcc_s.so.1" \) -exec mv "{}" "{}.bak" \; -print
/home/max/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
/home/max/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1

Comment: @MaxKulik install steam from Ubuntu repo.

Comment: @MaxKulik run this command to remove steam `sudo apt-get remove steam` to install `sudo apt-get install steam`

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: @MaxKulik have you tried to install a different driver. From additional drivers what GPU driver are you using.