# Steam not opening on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: steam

I downloaded steam and tried opening it. The icon flashed a few times but nothing happened.

I ran it with the terminal but it gave the following error message:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the following packages, or their equivalent for Ubuntu with:

   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`
2. Reboot the PC.
3. If that does not work, then, run (this is an one line command):

`find ~/.steam/root/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" -o -name "libgpg-error.so*" \) -print -delete`

4. Reboot again.