# Steam stopped working, reinstalling it didn't help

Tags: steam

A little while ago my steam stopped working. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling and that didn't work.

When I try to launch steam the icon just blinks 3 to 4 times and steam never opens.

Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit is the version I'm currently running.

I typed `steam` in terminal, and this was the dialog that came

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit 
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
```

Seems like it is in working order so I don't know what is wrong

EDIT : So after renaming the 2 directories `~/.steam*` and `~/.local/share/Steam` Steam comes up with a new error :

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: Open a terminal and run Steam from there by typing "steam" then enter. It should give some error messages. Please [edit] your question and post them inside {}.

Comment: Weird, it should be more text after that. It looks like it just stops but without giving a reason.

Comment: Could you please move all the per-user steam files (`~/.steam*`, `~/.local/share/Steam`, `~/.cache/steam`) out of the way and try again? The easiest way would be to rename them. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBay well, yeah. That basically explains what happens, I think.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That did not work, I tried renaming the files and re-launching and nothing changed except that the user liscense agreement popped up again. Also, the Directory `~/.cache/steam` did not exist.

Comment: @SomeLinuxFan Have a look at this answer, maybe it helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/614458/522934

Comment: `steam --reset` is indeed another worthwhile thing to try.

Comment: @DavidFoerster With the latest update/edit we have something to start troubleshooting. Perhaps the question should be reopened. I think the problem now is the same as discussed in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193802

Comment: Looks like there are actually two unrelated issues and the resolution of the first one uncovered the second one. The possible duplicate are (1) [Can't Launch Steam No Errors In terminal (Ubuntu 14.04)](/q/644936/175814) and (2) [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](/q/614422/175814).