# Can't login to Steam under Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, steam

I recently switched to Ubuntu 15.04 and installed Steam. The installation went fine and Steam does run, but as soon as I try to log in, I get an error telling me that either my account does not exist or I used the wrong password.
I have been trying a number of times, changing my password a couple of times, just to be sure but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Does anyone know how to approach this? Please try to answer newbie-friendly ;)

Comment: Have a look at this thread [Steam won't launch in Ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/613862/steam-wont-launch-in-ubuntu-15-04-x64) whether this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have entered your profile name instead of your account name. Your account name is what you use to log into Steam, and your profile name is your public name. If you have another computer that's logged into your Steam account then you can go to Settings and you should see your account name there.

Comment: oh my, I'm feeling pretty silly now. I tried logging in with my registered email instead of my profile name, thanks for the help :)